How to Update Firefox on shutdown
I want to make sure that the user isn't disturbed by a firefox update ("Pls restart Firefox"), therefore i excluded firefox* from the auto-update.
I used Ubuntu Mate 22.04 before and this script worked:
https://github.com/Linux-Installation/Linux-Mint-Installations-Script/blob/dev/download/firefoxUpdateOnShutdown.service
The Problem is that it stops in the middle of the execution:
I tested it with
ExecStart=sh -c 'apt install -y --only-upgrade firefox* > /home/jokergermany/firefoxupdateonshutdown.txt'

Paketlisten werden gelesen… Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… firefox-dbg wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-dev wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-geckodriver wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-mozsymbols wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-af wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-an wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ar wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-as wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ast wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-az wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-be wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-bg wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-bn wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-br wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-bs wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ca wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-cak wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-cs wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-csb wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-cy wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-da wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-el wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-eo wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-es wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-et wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-eu wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-fa wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-fi wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-fr wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-fy wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ga wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-gd wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-gl wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-gn wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-gu wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-he wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-hi wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-hr wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-hsb wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-hu wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-hy wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ia wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-id wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-is wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-it wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ja wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ka wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-kab wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-kk wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-km wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-kn wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ko wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ku wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-lg wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-lt wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-lv wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-mai wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-mk wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ml wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-mn wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-mr wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ms wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-my wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-nb wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ne wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-nl wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-nn wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-nso wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-oc wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-or wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-pa wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-pl wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-pt wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ro wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ru wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-si wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-sk wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-sl wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-sq wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-sr wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-sv wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-sw wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-szl wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ta wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-te wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-th wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-tr wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-uk wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-ur wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-uz wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-vi wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-xh wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-zh-hans wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-zh-hant wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. firefox-locale-zu wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. webext-form-history-control wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. webext-lightbeam wird übersprungen; es ist nicht installiert und lediglich Upgrades sind angefordert. Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade): firefox firefox-locale-de firefox-locale-en 3 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 28 nicht aktualisiert. Es müssen 77,0 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden. Nach dieser Operation werden 1.071 kB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt. Ign:1 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64
129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:2 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:3 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:1 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:2 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:3 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:1 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64
129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:2 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:3 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:1 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:2 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:3 http://fastly.linuxmint.io wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:1 https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/packages.linuxmint.com wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:2 https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/packages.linuxmint.com wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:3 https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/packages.linuxmint.com wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:1 https://ftp.rz.uni-frankfurt.de/pub/mirrors/linux-mint/packages wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:2 https://ftp.rz.uni-frankfurt.de/pub/mirrors/linux-mint/packages wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Ign:3 https://ftp.rz.uni-frankfurt.de/pub/mirrors/linux-mint/packages wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma Fehl:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com wilma/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma »fastly.linuxmint.io« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden. Fehl:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-de amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma »fastly.linuxmint.io« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden. Fehl:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com wilma/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 129.0+linuxmint1+wilma »fastly.linuxmint.io« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.

What I tried:

Add a TimeoutStopSec=infinity
Add a /etc/systemd/systemd.conf.d/60_custom.conf with DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
change the DefaultTimeoutStopSec to 90s in /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/50_linuxmint.conf

Nothing works, what do I do wrong?
Edit:
The linked duplicate don't solve my problem...
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=nala install -y --download-only firefox
ExecStop=sh -c 'systemctl list-jobs | grep -q "poweroff.target.*start" && apt install -y --only-upgrade firefox*'
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStopSec=infinity

[Unit]
After=network-online.target
Description=Update Firefox on Shutdown

Don't work on my notebook
I suppose it only works for fast devices, because the shutdown process isn't stopped by this systemD service =(

just replace dnf5 update package1 with apt-get update -y firefox

Don't work on my notebook =(
BTW:
apt-get update -y firefox isn't a working command...

how is apt-get update -y firefox failing??


E: Der Befehl »update« akzeptiert keine Argumente. translated: the command update don't accept arguments


@JokerGermany you initially commented that this worked for you, what changed?

I thought it worked, changed from my desktop to the laptop and there it's not working.
I suppose it's only working on fast devices, because the script isn't stopping the shutdown process -__-
The same like with my old script which worked with ubuntu 22.04
https://github.com/Linux-Installation/Ubuntu-Installations-Script/blob/main/download/firefoxUpdateOnShutdown.service

Your test with the original service doesn't show much, it only redirects stdout. Redirect stderr as well: > /home/... 2>&1 so that we can see errors as well. And use [code block]s, not quote formatting, for command output. And add Environment=LC_ALL=C so that we can get output in English.

Sorry, out of frustation I made a a little break.


Even with Ubuntu Mate 22.04 I replaced the the snap firefox with a deb. package.


I switched from Ubuntu Mate 22.04 to Linux Mint 22.
The Problem occurs with Linux Mint.


I will now collect the data @muru asked for.

@muru
https://paste.tchncs.de/upload/ape-bear-lizard

don't know why it works now...

@JokerGermany perhaps because the firefox package had already been downloaded, so the script didn’t have to wait for that to finish before installing the upgrade, so the overall process took less time and finished before the system shut down.

@StephenKitt This would mean that the error still occours on slow systems...
Will test without the download tomorrow.
